# Read file in unknown directory

Tags: python, linux, wildcard, directory-structure

I need to read and edit serveral files, the issue is I know roughly where these files are but not entirely.

so all the files are called QqTest.py in various different directories.
I know that the parent directories are called:

```
mdcArray = ['MDC0021','MDC0022','MDC0036','MDC0055','MDC0057'
            'MDC0059','MDC0061','MDC0062','MDC0063','MDC0065'
            'MDC0066','MDC0086','MDC0095','MDC0098','MDC0106'
            'MDC0110','MDC0113','MDC0114','MDC0115','MDC0121'
            'MDC0126','MDC0128','MDC0135','MDC0141','MDC0143'
            'MDC0153','MDC0155','MDC0158']
```

but after that there is another unknown subdirectory that contains QqTest.txt

so I need to read the QqTest.txt from /MDC[number]/unknownDir/QqTest.txt

So how I wildcard read the file in python similar to how I would in bash
i.e

```
/MDC0022/*/QqTest.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Python module called `glob` to do this. It enables Unix style pathname pattern expansions.

```
import glob
glob.glob("/MDC0022/*/QqTest.txt")
```

If you want to do it for all items in the list you can try this.

```
for item in mdcArray:
    required_files = glob.glob("{0}/*/QqTest.txt".format(item))
    # process files here
```

[Glob documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.glob)

Answer (score 1):

You could search your root folders as follows:

```
import os

mdcArray = ['MDC0021','MDC0022','MDC0036','MDC0055','MDC0057'
            'MDC0059','MDC0061','MDC0062','MDC0063','MDC0065'
            'MDC0066','MDC0086','MDC0095','MDC0098','MDC0106'
            'MDC0110','MDC0113','MDC0114','MDC0115','MDC0121'
            'MDC0126','MDC0128','MDC0135','MDC0141','MDC0143'
            'MDC0153','MDC0155','MDC0158']

for root in mdcArray:
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(root):
        for filename in filenames:
            if filename == 'QqTest.txt':
                file = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
                print "Found - {}".format(file)
```

This would display something like the following:

```
Found - MDC0022\test\QqTest.txt
```

The [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html?highlight=os.walk#os.walk) function can be used to traverse your folder structure.

To search all folders for `MDC<number>` in the path, you could use the following approach:

```
import os
import re

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.'):
    if re.search(r'MDC\d+', dirpath):
        for filename in filenames:
            if filename == 'QqTest.txt':
                file = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
                print "Found - {}".format(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use os.walk. Not exactly what you wanted but will do the job.

```
rootDir = '.'
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
    print('Found directory: %s' % dirName)
```